# How to set the background of Rectangle with a picture?

Tags: c#, wpf, background

I create a Rectangle

```
public void Set(Rectangle maps, int y, int x) {
    Map.Children.Add(maps);
    maps.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, x);
    maps.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, y);

}
```

But How to change the background with "Resources/1.jpg"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```xml
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/YourAppName;component/Resources/1.jpg" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

EDITED AGAIN (Sorry)

Or in C#

```
maps.Fill = new ImageBrush {
    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/YourAppName;component/Resources/1.jpg", UriKind.Absolute))
};
```

Comment: An error :cant change "string"  to the System.Windows.Media.ImageSource

Comment: You change `YourAppName` from the name of your app?

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble using the "/YourAppName;" portion of the address as suggested by @Jonny Piazzi.  It probably works, I just couldn't get it to.  Alternatively, I was able to make this method work.

1)  I added the image to my project in a folder I created: Images > Backgrounds > JellyFishBackground.jpg

2)  I right clicked the image in Solution Explorer > Properties > Set Build Action to Resource

3) Build project

4) Simply target the image as such:  (in my case I targeted a row of my grid, and used a Stretch property, which are beyond the scope of this question, just fyi to avoid confusion)

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row ="0">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Backgrounds/JellyFishBackground.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```